# Is there only one Magic School Bus?

Tags: the-magic-school-bus

Is there only one Magic School Bus? Is Ms. Frizzle's bus unique, or are there other such buses in that universe?

Comment: No idea if [this](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Ms._Valerie_Frizzle) is accurate, but: *It is likely that she designed and built her magical bus herself or modified an original one.*

Comment: The other ones aren't buses. At least one of them appears as an old police phone box

Comment: I remember reading one of the books where they pass a different magic school bus from a different school. But I could have imagined it, its from many years ago.

Answer (score 7):

I can't find any reference to any other Magic School Buses, however, there is a [Magic Motorcycle](https://magicschoolbus.fandom.com/wiki/The_Motorcycle) that appears in *The Magic School Bus Rides Again*.

> The Motorcycle is the vehicle that is driven by Valerie Frizzle after she retired from being a teacher at Walkerville Elementary and gave the job to her younger sister Fiona Frizzle. It resembles The Magic School Bus as it also seems to have a mind of it's own.

[image: Ms Frizzle rides The Motorcycle underwater]